# Specify variance structure TOEP(1) in lmer for mixed model

Tags: r, variance, sas, lme4-nlme

How can I do the following job in R? More specific: how can I define `type=toep(1)` in R?

```
PROC MIXED DATA=dlset COVTEST ASYCOV UPDATE; 
     CLASS block cross ; 
     MODEL Height = block; 
     RANDOM col1-col20/TYPE=TOEP(1); * GCA effects ; 
     RANDOM cross; * SCA effects ; 
     ODS OUTPUT COVPARMS=_varcomp ASYCOV=_cov; 
RUN;
```

Comment: good question, but not easy ...

Comment: I think you need to bite the bullet and use `lme` (in which you will look into `?pdClasses`) or `gee` (in which case you look into `corstr` to define a stationary M-dependent correlation structure (`stat_M_dep`)). Yeah, nothing obvious....